# How to detect stack navigator goBack() function in a component

Tags: react-native

I have stack navigators with a default header and an input component. What I want is when a user presses the back button on the header, check whether "input" state is empty or not and if its not empty show a modal or alert before run goBack() function. Is it possible to reach this function in a component or I have to define header in my component instead of Stack.Screen?

```
<Stack.Navigator>
    .
    .
    .
    <Stack.Screen
    name="New"
    component={NewScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

My NewScreen component with styled-component

```
const NewScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
   const [input, setInput] = useState("");
   return (
      <Container>
          <TextInput
            autoFocus
            placeholder="What's happening?"
            onChangeText={setInput}
          />
      </Container>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make a custom header inner that component

```
const NewScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
   const [input, setInput] = useState("");
const alert = () =>
    Alert.alert(
      "Alert Title",
      "My Alert Msg",
      [
        {
          text: "Ask me later",
          onPress: () => console.log("Ask me later pressed")
        },
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
          style: "cancel"
        },
        { text: "OK", onPress: () => {
              navigation.goBack();
          } }
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
   return (
      <Container>
         <View style={{width: '100%', height:'30'}}>
             <ButtonIcon onPress={() => {
               if(input && input !== ''){
                   alert();
               }
             
            }}/>
          </View>
          <TextInput
            autoFocus
            placeholder="What's happening?"
            onChangeText={setInput}
          />
      </Container>
}
```